# Android handler skip/jump a second

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a simple digital clock with second and two colons changing every second. I have thought about using DigitalClock but I want the colons to flash as well as the second and don't want to show am/pm. So I read the "Updating the UI from a Timer" and it suggests us to use Handler. So i use Handler and can change second and colons every second but the weird thing is that sometimes, it jumps a second (1,2,4,5,6). It seems the clock is a bit lagging. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

```
tick_handler = new Handler();
    Runnable updateSecond = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            second.setText(DataModel.getSeconds());
            if(colon1.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
                colon1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                colon2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                colon1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                colon2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            tick_handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
tick_handler.postDelayed(updateSecond, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you see this on the emulator as it is much slower than actual phones. Try changing the `tick_handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` to a smaller value than 1 second, for e.g. 500 ms

```
tick_handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
```

and add a global variable to track the differece between each time the thread runs and if the difference is 1 second, update the Views.

Comment: Hi, thanks and I am using emulator. Just changed 1000 to 500 and the second stopped jumping but sometimes, it changes really fast(34,35,quickly change to 36). It might be the problem that I am running it on emulator as I used Thread.sleep(1000), and the same thing happens. So I guess you are right and I will try to get a real machine to test. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you missed the second part of my answer. You need to create a global variable that starts counting the millis each time you run the thread and only runs the second.setText() method and changes the visibility of the views when the accumlation reaches 3600

Comment: Using a global variable works! Thanks! I check if the SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - global_variable > 1000 and then run the setText() code. Thanks again!!!